# How can I calculate the duration a contact has been in any of the availability states in this database?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Given the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Contact]
(
    [Id] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [Uri] CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [Availability]
(
    [Id] TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [Name] CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [ContactAvailability]
(
    [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [ContactId] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [AvailabilityId] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL
);
```

I am attempting to get a list of all of the contacts and the durations for which they have been in any of the availabilities for the current day.

The `ContactAvailability` table ends up having records such as:

```
(1, 1, 1, '01/01/2014 08:00:23.51 -07:00'),
(2, 1, 3, '01/01/2014 08:15:38.01 -07:00'),
(3, 1, 3, '01/01/2014 08:15:38.02 -07:00'),
(4, 2, 2, '01/01/2014 08:18:33.12 -07:00')
```

These records represent a `Contact`'s transition from one `Availability` to another, and also from one `Availability` to the same. It is essentially a running status that is logged on an interval.

The query I have come up with only queries for a particular user and only gets a list of their availabilities for the current day, but it won't calculate how long the `Contact` has been in any `Availability`. I am not sure where to start when it comes to that.

This is that query:

```
SELECT [Contact].[Uri] AS [ContactUri],
       [Availability].[Name] AS [AvailabilityName],
       [ContactAvailability].[CreatedOn]
FROM [ContactAvailability]
INNER JOIN [Contact] ON [Contact].[Id] = [ContactAvailability].[ContactId]
INNER JOIN [Availability] ON [Availability].[Id] = [ContactAvailability].[AvailabilityId]
WHERE [Contact].[Uri] = 'sip:contact@example.com' AND
      [ContactAvailability].[CreatedOn] >= '06/30/2014 00:00:00 -07:00' AND
      [ContactAvailability].[CreatedOn] < '07/01/2014 00:00:00 -07:00'
```

Comment: With the data in the question what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Window Function in combination with a CTE.

I think this should work, not tested yet :) So you might have to change your column names.

```
with SourceTable 
( ContactID, AvailabilityID, NewDate, OldDate)
as(
SELECT ContactAvailability.ContactID AS ContactID,
       ContactAvailability.AvailabilityID AS AvailabilityID,
       [ContactAvailability].[CreatedOn] As NewDate,
       LAG(ContactAvailability.CreatedON) OVER (Partition By ContactAvailability.ContactID order by ContactAvailability.CreatedOn) as OldDate

FROM [ContactAvailability])

SELECT [Contact].[Uri] AS [ContactUri],
       [Availability].[Name] AS [AvailabilityName],
       SourceTable.OldDate as PreviousAvailabilityDate,
       SourceTable.NewDate as CurrentAvailibilityDate,
       SourceTable.NewDate - SourceTable.OldDate as DifferenceBetweenAvailability,
       [ContactAvailability].[CreatedOn]
FROM SourceTable
INNER JOIN [Contact] ON [Contact].[Id] = SourceTable.[ContactId]
INNER JOIN [Availability] ON [Availability].[Id] = SourceTable.[AvailabilityId]
```

If you need to calculate the total time somebody has been in a certain availability (f.e. personA is in availability A then B then A again and then C) you will have to add another cte and partition on ContactAvailability.AvailabilityID and then make a sum of your calculated field.